# Migrate source id's and map them to already existing Drupal entity id's

Tags: 8, migrations

I've tried a bunch of different setups, but I can't get it to work. Here are the two setups I was the most confident in that it would work. I simply want to map existing id's in the source to new id's that are already created in taxonomy.

Attempt 1:

```
  field_season:
    # Map the seasons to our already existing taxonomy terms
    -
      plugin: static_map
      source: season
      map:
        '1': 26 # Lente
        '2': 29 # Zomer
        '3': 24 # Herfst
        '4': 28 # Winter
    -
      plugin: entity_lookup
      value_key: tid
      entity_type: taxonomy_term
      bundle_key: tid
      bundle: seasons
```

Attempt 2:

```
  field_season:
    plugin: iterator
    source: field_season
    process:
      target_id:
        # Map the seasons to our already existing taxonomy terms
        plugin: static_map
        source: season
        map:
          '1': 26 # Lente
          '2': 29 # Zomer
          '3': 24 # Herfst
          '4': 28 # Winter
```

Edit: FWIW, all the other processes work just fine!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens to me all the time, I post a question after fiddling around for hours and shortly after, I manage to find the answer myself. It appears that the first attempt was almost right. Though `bundle_key` should be `vid`, I'm not sure why though.

The config, for completeness sake.

```
  field_season:
    # Map the seasons to our already existing taxonomy terms
    -
      plugin: static_map
      source: season
      map:
        '1': 26 # Lente
        '2': 29 # Zomer
        '3': 24 # Herfst
        '4': 28 # Winter
    -
      plugin: entity_lookup
      value_key: tid
      entity_type: taxonomy_term
      bundle_key: vid
      bundle: seasons
```

Answer (score 0):

The entity_lookup doesn't appear to be doing anything here - it's retrieving D8 terms by their tid, and returning their tid. The static_map alone should do it if you know the mappings from the original tids to the new D8 tids.